# Winforms: How do I transition from application landing page to main screen after login

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

**Background**

When my application is launched, a full screen main window/form is opened up. When not logged in, the main windows shows a landing "page" which is simple but attractive - having a title, company logo, and a login button. When the login button is clicked, a smaller login window opens where a user can input their credentials. After correct credentials are entered, the main window (currently showing the landing "page") is instructed to show the main contents of the application.

Now, the ugly part: in order to show/hide the landing "page" vs. main application content, my main window uses a split container that essentially fills the whole form. This container always has one panel collapsed (either the one holding the landing "page" or the panel holding the main application contents). When a user logs in, the landing "page" panel is collapsed, and the main contents are un-collapsed.

**Question**

Assuming that what I'm doing here is terrible/awful, what is an alternative for transitioning from my landing "page" to the main application content without having a separate form for each?

I've seen many people load just the login dialog when the application starts, and then only load the main windows once there is a successful login. I'm trying to avoid this because I don't want to lose my landing "page".

Comment: One thing for sure is I wouldn't use the method you're using i.e. Split Container. Why not create your landing page as a UserControl, add it to your main page and dock to use the full area, then load the main page, display your login over it and if login is successful, hide/remove the user control from your main page and continue as normal.

Comment: The main contents of the application is a large set of various user controls where everything is docked, taking up the entire window. How do I add a docked control that sits over all of that?

Comment: "How do I add a docked control that sits over all of that?"  You can have as many controls as you like occupy the same area.  The z-order determines what you see overlaid on what else.  You can add another control - `UserControl` or otherwise - to your form, right click it and select Bring To Front and it will then cover anything else on the form.  To get at the other controls, simply right-click it and choose Send To Back.  You can also use the Document Outline window to change the z-order.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but I have so many controls fully docked in my application that once the landing page control is sent to the back, I don't know how to bring it to the front again (it's not right-click-able).